# Buy SDK JavaScript, commission?

Tags: javascript, sdk, shopify, web-frontend, online-store

I found a plugin while going through google, called Buy SDK which is powered by Shopify, so I was wondering, if I make an online shop to sell goods, it would be done through Shopify in some way I assume, so is there some kind of commission or percentage that goes to Shopify or else where? Meaning I will not receive exact money a customer pays?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it costs. Have a look here for details on shopify: https://www.shopify.co.uk/faq/how-much-does-shopify-cost